# Ordering a nested collection

Tags: neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j

We have an entity like this

```
@NodeEntity(label = "User")
public class UserEntity {
    @GraphId
    private Long mId;

    @Property(name = "address")
    private String address;

    @Relationship(type="FRIEND_WITH", direction = Relationship.INCOMING)
    private List<UserEntity> friends;

    @Relationship(type="OWNS")
    private List<CarEntity> cars;
```

and we would like to retrieve a list of User hydrated up to one level with the collections ordered by a property (creationDate).

We started with this but we don't know how to order the collections

```
MATCH p = (u:User) - [*0..1] - () WHERE <condition> RETURN nodes(p), relationships(p)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keeping order of results in mapped collections becomes ambiguous when your path has length > 2 and can have cycles.

If you want to impose order on collections of relationships you have several options:

- use a -SortedSet- and implement `Comparable` in your entities
- sort relationships in setter method

You can sort either by a property of a related node or by relationship property - for that you need a relationship entity.

Comment: So, I have to sort the result java side. I can't do it by cypher, right?

Comment: Yes, OGM would net keep the order even if you did.